# iPhone X: Deleting old backup

Tags: iphone, ios, backup

Does deleting an old backup just delete the backup? So that I have more room in my iCloud to do another backup?

Just want to make sure if it doesn't wipe out everything on my iPhone.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Where are you deleting the backup from?

Comment: Under icloud backup

Answer (score 1):

Yes, deleting an iPhone backup just delete the backup and doesn't delete any data/content or configuration settings from your iPhone.

Yes, deleting a backup from iCloud indeed frees up space that can be used for other purposes.